# Is it correct that not all projections are self adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is it corrrect that not all projections on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\langle,\rangle)$(linear maps with $P^2=P$) are self adjoint, although all orthogonal projections are?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask if a linear map of a vector space is self-adjoint. We need a scalar product (or at least a non-degenerate bilinear form) in order to define adjoints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: consider the matrix

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$